# How do I return Notification at AppCenter

Tags: xamarin, notifications, visual-studio-app-center

I'm Xamarin Developer

I try to Send Notification thorough AppCenter.

So I success to Send AppCenter - My App.

But My App - AppCenter - My App Communication is not Work.

the First My App - AppCenter is Fine, But Appcenter - My App Can't Receive Notofication.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtQBt.png)

```
var receiptInstallID = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "xxxxxxxxx", "Android" },
                };

            AppCenterPush appCenterPush = new AppCenterPush(receiptInstallID);

            await appCenterPush.Notify("{YOUR_TITLE}", "{YOUR_MESSAGE}", null);
```

Does Have Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit - can you send verbose logs as the very least? It is hard to tell what's wrong with SDK at this point. `AppCenter.LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose;` would enable verbose logging.

Comment: I'm glad your Opinion. but there is a Problem to use your Code. It occurs "I/Choreographer( 8900): Skipped 4996 frames!" so I can't Take Log... Is there any Idea to use Notification In Xamarin Except Appcenter?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure that your problem is related to App Center SDK. I'd suggest opening a support ticket on appcenter.ms portal, in the bottom-right corner the blue support bubble